# check if a value is in an array

Tags: solr, lucene

Simple request, not sure how to do it in solr.  My SQL query would be like:

```
 select * from sometable where fieldvalue in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Is this possible in solr or would I have to do multiple queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solr equivalent is:

```
/select?q=fieldvalue:(a OR b OR c OR d)
```